# How can I convert a Rhino-produced JSON datastructure (NativeObject) to Java datastructure?

Tags: java, json, rhino

I am trying to generate a data structure inside JavaScript code, and process the results from Java (Rhino in Java 6 or 7).

I succeeded in invoking the JS function from Java using:

```
Object result = invocableEngine.invokeFunction(functionName, parameters);
```

Now, on JS side, that result is a JSON data structure as follows:

```
{ 
  "key1" : { "key1_1" : "value1_1", "key1_2" : 11 },

  "key2" : [ {  "key2_1": "foo2"
              , "key2_1" : "bar2" },

             {  "key2_1": "foo2"
              , "key2_1" : "bar2"
              , "key2_3" : [1,2,3] } ]
}
```

On the Java side, however, "result" is an object of type `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeObject`

**Is there a way for me to convert it to a reasonable Java datastructure**, without having the overhead of serializing that JSON to a string and then using Gson to parse it?

Assume for the moment that the data structure is reasonably well defined, e.g.
I know that the object is a hash with keys "key1" and "key2", the first maps to a hash with keys "key1_1" and "key1_2"; the second maps to an array of hashes, each of which has keys "key2_1" and "key2_2" that are scalar and "key2_3" which is an array.

My 2 priorities are, in that order:

1. Performance (which is one reason why I'm wary of serialize + Gson-parse)
2. Portability between Java 6, 7 and 8 (however, I'd prefer a materially faster non-portable solution).

Comment: is there a problem with leaving it in Rhino format and accessing it through that data structure? I recognize that it would have some overhead but I dont think there are any alternatives without converting to string and deserializing.

Comment: @ghostbust555 - I think that "accessing through Rhino format" is a valid approach, but not sure how to do this. There doesnt' seem to be any decent documentation I can find, especially for hashes

Comment: huh. wow they have just the worst documentation of all time. Try result.getAttributes("key1")?

Comment: Why dont you use objectmapper??

Comment: What specifically is the problem with using gson?

Comment: @BlackPOP - if you mean the one from Jackson, is that any different from using Gson? It seems to convert JSON string, not a NativeObject

Comment: @Bohemian - Problem #1: I already have a NativeObject. I don't think Gson works with that? Problem #2: I am worried about performance (adding parsing overhead for a large-ish JSON file is a concern). Granted, I didn't benchmark. Having said that, I WOULD accept (and bounty) an answer that relies on parsing BUT proves sufficiently it's not meaningfully slower on larger JSON files (let's say arrays size 1000)

Comment: @DVK You can form an object from json String. final nativeObject propertyObj = mapper.readValue(JsonString, nativeObject .class);

Answer (score 1):

This is the code from NativeObject to JSONObject.
I think from NativeObject to Map is similar.

```java
    public static JSONObject toJsonObject(NativeObject nativeObject)
    {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        Set<Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet = nativeObject.entrySet();
        for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : entrySet)
        {
            try
            {
                if (entry.getValue() instanceof String)
                {
                    object.put(entry.getKey().toString(), new JSONObject(entry.getValue().toString()));
                }
                else if (entry.getValue() instanceof NativeArray)
                {
                    object.put(entry.getKey().toString(), toJsonArray((NativeArray) entry.getValue()));
                }
                else if (entry.getValue() instanceof NativeObject)
                {
                    object.put(entry.getKey().toString(), toJsonObject((NativeObject) entry.getValue()));
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                try
                {
                    object.put(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
                }
                catch (JSONException ignored)
                {
                }
            }
        }


        return object;
    }

    public static JSONArray toJsonArray(NativeArray nativeArray)
    {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        for (Object o : nativeArray)
        {
            if (o instanceof NativeObject)
            {
                array.put(toJsonObject((NativeObject) o));
            }
            else if (o instanceof NativeArray)
            {
                array.put(toJsonArray((NativeArray) o));
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    array.put(new JSONObject(o.toString()));
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    array.put(o.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse any json string "object" using `Gson` by parsing it into a `LinkedTreeMap`, like this:

```
import com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap;

String json = <your raw json>
LinkedTreeMap map = new Gson().fromJson(json, LinkedTreeMap.class);
```

After parsing your sample input, here's an example of how to use it:

```
System.out.println(((List<LinkedTreeMap>)map.get("key2")).get(1).get("key2_3"));
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

It helps to know the structure beforehand, but isn't essential because you can inspect the type of each node as you get it.

As for performance, I created sample input with 4 keys each with over 400 entries in the list. After a JVM warn up, the parsing took just 2ms on my low-spec old laptop.

Answer (score -1):

You can build java object from inside of json.

Something like this (i am constructing new java.lang.String, but similarly you can construct your own class):

```
java -jar js.jar
Rhino 1.7 release 5 2015 01 29
js> str=new java.lang.String("Hello world")
Hello world
js> java.lang.System.out.println(str)
Hello world
```

Comment: He asked something speifically!